# Listing files in "/sdcard/" returns null?

Tags: android, file, internal-storage

I have an app that needs access to an android phone's internal storage, such as the Download folder. However when I try to list the files it alimport

```
java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        File root = new File("/"); // Works
        File mnt = new File("/mnt/"); // Works
        File mnt2 = new File("/mnt/m_internal_storage"); // Crashes
        File cus = new File("/custom/"); // Works
        File f = new File("/sdcard/"); // Crashes
        String[] s =  f.list();
        for (int x = 0; x < s.length; x++) {
            Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "#", s[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

This code will print every file in the directory. It works with `root`, `mnt` & `cus` but crashes when it tries to get the list of `f` & `mnt2`, returning a `null` array to `s`. How do I access the internal file storage?

I have also tried using `Environment`'s functions with most failing and I even have Read/Write permissions for External Storage enabled.

Compiling for 7.0.
Targeting API 23.
Min sdk API 18.

Answer (score 3):

> I have an app that needs access to an android phone's internal storage, such as the Download folder.

The `Download` folder that users see is on what the Android SDK calls [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

> How do I access the internal file storage?

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. **Never hardcode paths**. For example, vanishingly few devices on the face of the planet have `/mnt/m_internal_storage`, `/custom/`, or `/sdacard/`.

> I have also tried using Environment's functions with most failing and I even have Read/Write permissions for External Storage enabled.

Perhaps you did not implement [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: I'm using a file explore to see my phone's files outside of programming. My phone has both an internal Download folder and external one. Like I said `Environment` doesn't work and I was using hardcode to tell the extact dir. Thirdly you need runtime permissions to R/W to internal storage?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage says nothing about needing permissions for internal storage.

Comment: Also `/sdacard/` was a typo.

Comment: @CodedApple: "I'm using a file explore to see my phone's files outside of programming" -- you have no ability to see what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), using any tool, on production hardware, except on rooted devices. You can see external storage and possibly [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: @CodedApple: "`Environment` doesn't work" -- it does for everybody else. "...says nothing about needing permissions for internal storage" -- since you are not working with internal storage, that does not matter. You are working with external storage.

Comment: I'm not working with external storage. My phone has an internal, non removable sd card and an external one. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` gives me the removable card dir which is `"/mnt/m_external_sd"` where as I want what `"/mnt/m_internal_storage/"` leads to.

Comment: Also, when I said "Environment doesn't work" I mean it just crashes like the hardcodes do.

Comment: @CodedApple: "where as I want what "/mnt/m_internal_storage/" leads to. " -- your device is seriously messed up. It is unlikely that there is any Android SDK support for that location. Contact the device manufacturer for assistance.

Comment: It's a shortcut file... but the list in mnt still detects it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code it is "File f = new File("/sdacard/"); // Crashes", which should be "/sdcard/".

Comment: That was just a typo in writing this question, it still changes nothing.

Answer (score 1):

if you want internal file of your app, means in app.package

```
/sdcard/data/data/pack_name/files/fileName
```

you need to access it like this

```
File p = getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath("FileName");
```

Edit
other than this you have to ask for runtime permissions
and Download Path is not Internal Storage! it defines as external.
everything that normal users can access (without root) in file manager is external storage. internal storage is not like internal sdcard and then micro sdcard. Internal Storage is what belong to ur package 
read it: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: That's not what I want, I want the internal download folder that apps like Chrome download files to.