# File choosing error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, filechooser

I have an android application that choosing image. The file uri is obtaining correctly.

```
RequestBody requestFile=null;
        File file=null;
        String filePath=getPath(fileUri).trim(); // getting same filepath choosing via gallery or other file manager
        if (fileUri!= null )
            try{
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                file = FileUtils.getFile(getActivity(),fileUri); // neglect this line Iam using api below 19
                else {
                    file=new File(filePath); // TODO: 30-Mar-17 CORRECT THE ERROR FOR API BELOW 19
                }
                String haaii="sdf";
                String g=file.getAbsolutePath(); //excecuting when choosing file manager.
                requestFile = RequestBody.create(
                        MediaType.parse(context.getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)),
                        file
                );  // weired not excecuting..null pointer expet choosing via gallery
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("multipart",e.toString());
            }
            else Log.e("fileuri","uri is null");
```

path method

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {

        String path = null;
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        if(cursor == null){
            path = uri.getPath();
        }
        else{
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]);
            path = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
        }

        return ((path == null || path.isEmpty()) ? (uri.getPath()) : path);
    }
```

choosing file

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        // Show only images, no videos or anything else
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

result is obtained using

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            uri = data.getData();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
                // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));

                photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

When choosing via file manager -getting error
[image]

```
E/multipart: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

when choosing via gallery -ok
[image]
But the error is strange. When choosing via gallery it is okay. But when using the file manager getting null pointer exception. But string value `filePath` is same when choosing via file manager or gallery. **How to solve this?. But when I remove try catch block the null pointer exception is not showing, but the next line is not executing..**

Comment: NullPointerException? Then tell which pointer/variable was null on which code line or statement. And why did not you post your file choose code in the first block? And then on acticity result code? And when is the code in the first block executed? I see no connection between onActivityResult and the rest of your code. And what is it that you need a path for where you have a nice uri?

Comment: `When choosing via gallery it is okay. But when using the file manager `. You get an uri from them. Show of both uri.toString() and uri.getPath() please.

Comment: @greenapps I am passing the revealed Uri to get path method you can see the break pointed Uri value in the image

Comment: maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519577/listing-files-in-sdcard-returns-null

Comment: You have not answered my questions at all. Strange. One would think you seek help.